# transparent renders having very dark undertones

Tags: materials, transparency, lighting, reflection

I don't know how to describe it but my transparent renders always come out having dark edges despite bumping the lights to the maximum I can without loosing details in my object.no matter what I do it never really comes out fully transparent of aesthetically pleasing. please does anybody have any advice on what i can do. i need to export the image to an image editor and work with the transparent object. any advice will be appreciated.

this is how my project setup looks like

https://imgur.com/nDX71LU

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the moment you have no HDRI image for your World and the *Background* color is dark grey, maybe give it an HDRI or change the color? The third one is a mix with a *Transparent* shader with a *Layer Weight* as factor:

[image]

File: [image]

Suggestion for your *World* material, maybe try a mix between 2 *Background*, with an *Input > Light Path* node as factor, to be able to choose a diffuse effect that will be different from the reflection, etc:

[image]

Comment: i tired that, but it still manages to have does grey areas around the object. you feel me? yours still has grey areas around it, despite your hdri being around it. and at the cost of this it seems like the inner material looses its shadow details. :(

Comment: In that case maybe cheat a bit (see my edit)?

Comment: ohh! looking better let me play around with this and get back to you

Comment: or is there a way i can filter out a particular color from an object, since it's mostly the grey i want to get rid of, instead of reducing the transparency as a whole. i'm not sure why blender does not make it easy to export clean transparent models lol

Comment: hi, so i went back to the file where i had an issue with the cup and was playing around with some things. and i think i kind of got the result i was looking for https://imgur.com/a/zDklivA

Comment: let me see if I can try it with this one!

Comment: Oh OK great then ;)  .............

Comment: lol its still having the same issue.. fml ahaha https://imgur.com/a/zDklivA

Comment: if blender is not able to do this, as a last resort is there an other 3d software i can use to just render transparency. Ive tweaked every setting possible ahaha

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you're talking about, you'll always see the thickness, if you want transparency then I guess you need to mix with a Transparent shader (i.e. my third object)?

Comment: i want to get rid of those grey areas without really loosing transparency. because any place i put it over covers it with grey reflections just like the blue i have there.

Comment: it looks like the bottle is dirty or has black liquid stains inside

Comment: Oh ok you're talking about the bottle, as I said you need to choose a bright HDRI or change the World Background color, which doesn't seem to be the case, and if it's still too dark mix your Principled BSDF with Transparent shader (see my 3rd bottle)

Comment: I've added the file ifit ever helps

Comment: that's the thing, if i make the world shader or hdri too bright i will loose details on the model inside, and even then it still appears dull, the transparent shader helps but its looks faded.. the cup quality i rendered is what i'm trying to get now. so sorry im stressing you. im just new to blender so most of these things i'm not certain

Comment: in that case maybe try a mix in your World material, mix (with the Mix Shader node) the current Background with another one, use an Input > Light Path node as factor and try the Glossy output or Diffuse output, etc, in order to have a different light and reflection?

Comment: do you mind if i communicate to you by chat?

Comment: you can join me on this discord: https://discord.gg/E6wXbR7A5S

Comment: Hi, guys, I'll set up a chat-room on BSE, as an alternative.. whichever you like... once you give me permission, I'll trim back the comments here.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148898/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-transparent-renders-having-very-dark-undertone); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.